# cannot load such file error in making app in ruby

Tags: ruby

While making an application in `ruby on rails` I got the following error:

```
ajeet@ajeetpc:~$ rails new first_app
/home/ajeet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
from /home/ajeet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ajeet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/ajeet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you do `rvm gemset list`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `rails` gem is not installed properly. Try to fix it

```
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails
```

then run `rails new first_app` again.